# Where does Git store tags?

Tags: git, tags

Where does Git store tags? I execute:

```
$ git tag
v0.1.0
v0.10.0
v0.11.0
```

But the directory `.git/refs/tags` is empty. Where does Git store these tags?

Thank you.

Comment: Where Git gets tags... that sounds like a tongue-twister!

Answer (score 27):

They can also be stored in `.git/packed-refs`

Comment: Yes, you are right.  After running `git gc --aggressive --prune`, I saw a tag that I had created earlier had disappeared from `.git/refs/tags`, but appeared in `.git/packed-refs`.  Note that `.git/packed-refs` is a file, not a directory, so you must `cat .git/packed-refs` to see the tags.

Comment: In fact, that's the only place they'll ultimately be stored. They're packed up by `git gc`, and never unpacked, since they never change. And really, if you're trying to do anything besides satisfy your curiosity, the best way to examine things is through `git tag` or `git for-each-ref [refs/tags]`, not by looking directly in the .git directory.

Comment: Jefromi, the tags are packed by `git gc`, but between "pack" points, git creates unpacked commit objects and unpacked tags.

Comment: Also see the [git-pack-refs](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html) command.

Comment: See the command in the official documentation page : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs

Answer (score 9):

While wnoise is correct when he [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503773/where-does-git-store-tags/5504066#5504066) that Git also stores tags in `.git/packed-refs` following a `git gc` operation, between "pack" points (meaning, between `git gc` operations), Git creates unpacked commit objects and unpacked tags:

```
derek@derek-OptiPlex-960:~/Projects/test$ git tag
1
2
3
derek@derek-OptiPlex-960:~/Projects/test$ cat .git/packed-refs 
# pack-refs with: peeled 
55a87ab06897aca29285e58beb4e0de15af409fa refs/heads/master
89a6b171ee6d56bc3ce5a4cbd92c6a379594d974 refs/tags/1
55a87ab06897aca29285e58beb4e0de15af409fa refs/tags/2
derek@derek-OptiPlex-960:~/Projects/test$ ls .git/refs/tags
3
derek@derek-OptiPlex-960:~/Projects/test$
```