# Branch and tag information disappeared from the refs area in git

Tags: git, github

After test-driving a git GUI application (SmartGit, in case it makes a difference), I've noticed that my `.git/refs/heads` directory contains only "master" (there should be three other branches listed), and my `.git/refs/tags` directory is completely empty. This is in my local copy, the project itself is hosted on GitHub. When I browse it on GitHub, (thankfully) everything is still there.

What's the best way to restore my local branch and tag information? I know that the files in those directories just contain the SHA of the object they point to, but I'm a fairly basic-level git user.

Randy

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your .git/config file has gone missing since it stores information about local branches and what branches they are tracking. You need to checkout these branches again like this:

```
git checkout --track origin/branch1
git checkout --track origin/branch2
```

This will recreate the branches and make sure they track the remote branches. To update your tags you need to do:

```
git fetch --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `git branch -a` print?  The refs may have been packed by git.

Comment: `git branch -a` shows the "missing" branches as being known to exist on `remotes/origin/...` (as appropriate for each branch name).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I think this might be the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5504066/2272572

The refs are in the file `.git/packed-refs`