# How can I restore git tags?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I had to reinstall Windows. After I cloned my repos from GitHub, I observed that all my tags were gone. I did not know that they are not committed automatically.
However, before I reinstalled Windows, I copied my hard drive to an external drive. There, I found my tags in `poject1\.git\refs\tags`. I copied the tags to my new clone, opened Visual Studio and all the tags were back.
But, this did not work for a second project, where the backup folder `poject2\.git\refs\tags` is empty. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503773/where-does-git-store-tags), I learned that the tags can also be stored in `.git/packed-refs`. I copied this file to my new clone and indeed, it worked. I have all my tags back. But, Visual Studio also tells me, that there are 11 commits, that are not pushed yet. But that is not true and I fear to damage something, when I again push the changes. So, I copied back the `packed-refs` file. Now, there are no not-pushed changes but of course also my tags are gone.
What could I do, to get my tags back? Is it e. g. save, to copy the line
16128508741561153db64253e8545c7916b6f8b7 refs/tags/app_2.0
from my `packed-refs` backup to the new `packed-refs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch them from your backup:

```
cd /path/to/newrepo
git fetch /path/to/your/backup refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

or push to your current repo:

```
cd /path/to/your/backup
git push /path/to/newrepo --tags
```

- [How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git)
- [Does "git fetch --tags" include "git fetch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204190/does-git-fetch-tags-include-git-fetch)

Comment: Maybe this is cleaner for project1, where there are files in the folder `.git\refs\tags`. But my main problem is, that for project2, this folder is empty and the tags are stored inside the file `packed-refs`.

Comment: @Flippowitsch `git fetch` does not discriminate between loose refs and packed refs, Git handles refs in the `refs/tags` directory and the `packed-refs` file transparently.

Comment: OK. I will try. Is "/path/to/newrepo" the path to the *.sln file or to the `.git` folder?

Comment: @Flippowitsch usually the work tree, but it doesn't really matter in this case

Comment: You saved my day. Many thanks. Just in case anyone else faces this problem: The path to the backup must not contain spaces. If so, put it in double quotes.